# Is it possible to have a IF condition inside a Haskell Sqlite3 trigger?

Tags: haskell, if-statement, triggers, sqlite

Is it possible to modify the following HDBC and Sqlite 3 trigger in a way it contains a if condition  ?  And on meeting the condition only the UPDATE statement should be executed

```
calculateNoOfStocksTraded::String->Database.HDBC.Sqlite3.Connection->IO ()
calculateNoOfStocksTraded code conn=do                                                                               
                                    run conn " CREATE TRIGGER calcStocks \
                                               \ AFTER INSERT ON historicalData \
                                               \ FOR EACH ROW \
                                               \ BEGIN \
                                               \ UPDATE company \
                                               \ SET noOfStocks=(SELECT SUM(volume) FROM historicalData  WHERE companyCode= ? ); \
                                               \ END; " [toSql code]

                                    commit conn
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic should be something like this:

```
someCondition :: Maybe String
someCondition = if undefined -- define your condition here
                then "SQL UPDATE QUERY 1"
                else "SQL UPDATE QUERY 2"

calculateNoOfStocksTraded::String-> Database.HDBC.Sqlite3.Connection->IO ()
calculateNoOfStocksTraded code conn = do run conn query [toSql code]
                                         commit conn
    where query = someCondition
```

Comment: Thanx ! But It is necessary to use a trigger for this. any idea ?

Comment: @user3032393 So, if the condition becomes True, you only want the update query to be executed ?

Comment: yes..that's the requirement..and when the condition becomes false I want another update query to be executed. pls help me out

Comment: @user3032393 Updated the answer, but there really isn't anything tricky about that.

Comment: Actually, I want all this inside the trigger . I mean, checking the condition and then updating etc. Is that possible ?

Comment: Hi ! I  actually found  a way to do that. But there's  a syntax error. Can you help me to locate it ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847704/haskell-sqlite-3-case-statement-syntax-error