# Haskell Sqlite 3 CASE statement syntax error

Tags: sqlite, haskell, triggers, case

This is HDBC and Sqlite3. It says there's a syntax error near "CASE". But I can'd find such. Is there any ?

calculateNoOfStocksTraded::String->Database.HDBC.Sqlite3.Connection->IO ()
calculateNoOfStocksTraded code conn=do

```
                                run conn " CREATE TRIGGER calcStocks \
                                           \ AFTER INSERT ON historicalData \
                                           \ FOR EACH ROW \
                                           \ BEGIN \
                                           \ CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM historicalData) >= 1  THEN \
                                           \    UPDATE company \
                                           \    SET noOfStocks=(SELECT SUM(volume) FROM historicalData  WHERE companyCode= ? ) \
                                           \    WHERE code= ? ; \
                                           \ ELSE \
                                           \    UPDATE company \
                                           \    SET noOfStocks=0  \
                                           \    WHERE code= ? ; \
                                           \ END \

                                           \ END; " [toSql code,toSql code, toSql code]

                                commit conn
```

Answer (score 1):

[`CREATE TRIGGER`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) expects as the body of the trigger to be one of `update-stmt`, `insert-stmt`, `delete-stmt` or `select-stmt`;  So we need to rewrite the trigger in terms of one of those things;

<strike>As it turns out, you can simplify your trigger such that we can replace the `CASE` syntax with nothing; if `count(foo.*) < 1`, then it must be the case that `sum(foo.bar) = 0`  and thus:</strike>

In sqlite; `count(foo.*) < 1`, causes `sum(foo.bar) IS NULL` which is unfortunate;  but we can make it do the right thing by turning the `null` into a `0`  with `coalesce()`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER calcStocks
AFTER INSERT ON historicalData
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE company
   SET noOfStocks=(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(volume), 0) FROM historicalData  WHERE companyCode= ? )
   WHERE code= ? ;
END
```

Comment: when running for the first time, there's no tuple in the historicalData table. that's where the problem is. then it says "SqlNull" cannot be converted etc.